# Froyo freezes on bluetooth use

Tags: 2.2-froyo, bluetooth, system-freeze

Whenever i connect any bluetooth device, be it to my pc for copying files, another droid or my headset (Ive tried 3 different headsets) it freezes the system.

By freezing i mean if i get a phone call it rings in and i can answer with the headset. If its copying files it finishes. But i cant get back to the home screen.

The hardware buttons work, as if i hit the side button or the home button the screen lights up and the buttons do also but the system doesnt show, the screen stays lighted black. This is indefinately.

The only way ive found to get it back is taking the battery out.

Ive tried a couple bluetooth fixing programs and still nothing.

This doesnt happen from pairing alone or connecting. This only happens during long processes, ie anything that takes longer than about 2 minutes.

For instances copying a file or talking on the headset. If the call is under 2 minutes it goes right back to the system fully responsive.

The only thing i havent tried is flashing, i dont want to have to do that though.

This is a Galaxy Ace that i am using.

Answer (score -4):

I don't you're running out of available RAM. You should try using a memory booster like [GO Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.taskmanagerex) to clear some up.

Comment: I don't personally see how this could cause the problem. I never once use my home key to exit an App, always, always use the back button to close it out properly. That and I check my phone 3 or 4 times a day for open/active apps.

Comment: Also Joe, you need to use better English when posting on StackExchange sites. The abbreviation 'ur' is reserved for text messages only please.